# Accessing the latest robotframework python libraries when using Jython

Tags: python, maven, jython, robotframework

I am using [robotframework-maven-plugin](http://code.google.com/p/robotframework-maven-plugin/) which uses Jython version=2.5.1 for running my test cases.  My issue is when I try to use different robotframework libraries such the [robotframework-requests](https://github.com/bulkan/robotframework-requests) I get import errors as **I believe Jython version=2.5.1 does not have the latest Python libraries** required (Python version >= 2.6). I know this as the tests run when I use my installed version of python but do not when I use:

- maven robotframework:run command or
- the jybot command.

I would also like to use Curl but Jython version=2.5.1 again does not have the python library I need. I have tried coping over the files needed but this seem like the wrong solution and is very time consuming.  It seems I am stuck as I need maven robotframework and this uses Jython to run the test so is there a way that Robotframework Jython can have the latest Python libraries or is there a better approach?

Comment: A lot of robotframework python libraries required python version 2.6 or greater. Ex: github.com/bulkan/robotframework-requests which requires the request python library which requires python version 2.6 as it uses byte and io. I believe what is required is that the maven-robotframework plug-in needs to be upgraded to Jython 2.7 so that these new python libraries are installed by default. If or when this is to happen I am not sure about. Note: Robotframework currently installs Jython 2.5 by default.

Comment: People have tried to get this working with higher versions but not sure how successful they were [Google+ robotframework-devel](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/robotframework-devel/Ty4mJVP8_l8)